# NPM não continua instalação de pacote

Tags: node.js, npm

Estou tentando instalar um simples pacote com o NPM, mas a instalação não começa, sempre para no mesmo lugar.

```
C:\Users\Gabriel>npm install -g luaparse --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'luaparse',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@2.14.7
npm info using node@v4.2.0
npm verb install initial load of C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
npm verb cache add spec luaparse
npm verb addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for luaparse
npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/luaparse not in flight; fetching
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/luaparse
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 16:34:25
npm verb request id 197979e946371ad9
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/luaparse
-
```

Já tentei outros pacotes, e acontece a mesma coisa. Antes havia tentado com a versão 4.6 e 4.5 do node.js, mas acho que o problema está no meu computador, se puderem dar uma luz, eu agradeço.

**Edit:**
Quando estava tendo este problema, não conseguia pingar em nenhum ip/endereço, hoje consegui pingar, e ainda sim não consigo baixar nada.

**Edit:**
Instalei o node.js 6.19, e tem uma nova linha quando tento o mesmo comando:

```
[..................] - normalizeTree: http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/luaparse
```

É nela que pára.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54252/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-sales-npm-nao-continua-instalacao-de-pacote)

Answer (score 3):

- Desabilite o firewall de se roteador
- `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Se não funcionar, use um mirror pro npm:

```
npm config set registry http://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry
```

Depois use novamente o original:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

**Edit:** uma outra possível solução seria especificar o registry ao instalar o pacote.

Antes de tudo, limpe o cache do npm:

```
npm cache clean
```

E depois tente:

```
npm install luaparse --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

**Edit2:**
sabendo que você está usando DMZ, antes de tudo tente desabilitar o DMZ (reinicialização necessária)

Somente se não conseguir desabilitar, como o DMZ está encapsulando o DNS, tente setar o servidor DNS para automático:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

Pegue o ip de sua máquina utilizando `ipconfig` depois sete ele como servidor DMZ (está nas configurações NAT/DMZ/Advanced, dependendo de seu roteador)

Referências:

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry
http://www.projetoderedes.com.br/artigos/artigo_redes_de_perimetro.php
http://www.explorando.com.br/dmz-host/

Comment: Continua a não funcionar, pois não consigo pingar em npmjs.org.

Comment: @GabrielSales Você não está conseguindo pingar pois o firewall do roteador está ligado, desabilite-o. http://pt.wikihow.com/Desativar-o-Firewall-do-Roteador

Comment: Meu ip está como DMZ no roteador. Tentei "pingar' um endereço qualquer pelo meu celular, e continuou a não funcionar. Estranho que há um tempo atrás, conseguia pingar qualquer site

Comment: @GabrielSales Confira esse tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHT8bFZCs-w

Comment: Ola Renan, bom, como eu disse em outro comentário aqui, meu ip já está como DMZ no roteador. Minha conexão é via rádio, então não tenho acesso ao "modem".

Comment: @GabrielSales Você desabilitou o firewall do roteador? (por favor confirme pra mim), depois disso tente desativar o DMZ, o DMZ está encapsulando o DNS, por isso você não está conseguindo pingar certos sites. Confira minha resposta editada.

Comment: Renan, não há opção de desativar todo o firewall do meu roteador(Multilaser re160), apenas ativando o DMZ mesmo

Comment: @GabrielSales Como você não está conseguindo desativar o firewall do seu roteador nem desativar o DMZ, eu recomendo você procurar assistência técnica com seu provedor de internet a rádio, pois não há como eu saber como o DMZ está configurado em sua rede, não sei se seu provedor permite desativá-lo, e também não sei se seu provedor permite alterar o DNS. Encontramos a causa do problema, mas não consigo ir além disto.

Comment: Renan, eu tenho como desativar o DMZ sim, mas continua do mesmo jeito. Só não há opção de desativar o Firewall mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Gabriel, seguem alguns itens para você verificar:

1. O GIT está instalado?
2. Você consegue dar um clone em algum repositório externo (git clone https://github.com/Bigous/ng2-highcharts.git por exemplo)?
3. Como você já disse que não tem proxy, as variáveis de ambiente http_proxy e/ou https_proxy estão vazias? (verificar com o comando set sem parametros)?
4. Tem permissão de escrita no diretório "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Roaming\npm"?

Se em todas essas questões você responder sim, tente limpar o cache do npm, as vezes ele se corrompe e causa problemas estranhos:

```
npm cache clean
```

Comment: Olá @Bigous, respondendo: 1-Sim, 2-Sim, 3-Não existem, 4-sim. E já tentei dar clean. Obrigado, de qualquer forma.

Comment: Fala @GabrielSales, Você consegue pingar 52.27.70.152 ? se sim, tem um problema de DNS - para resolver pode alterar suas configurações do windows para o DNS da google por exemplo (8.8.8.8 e 8.8.4.4)

Comment: E ai. Bom, eu uso esse dns como padrão, e consigo pingar sim.

Comment: O DNS está configurado no router ou na sua máquina? pq se tiver no router, ele pode estar cacheando, daí, setando na máquina você resolve.
Se tiver na máquina, experimente dar um `ipconfig /flushdns` pra ver se ele refaz o cache local e resolve, mas se está pingando o problema é de dns, certeza, pois o IP acima é do npmjs.org

Comment: O DNS estava no router, botei no computador, dei flushdns, mas continua do mesmo jeito, obrigado a tentativa

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que baixe o [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), que é um controle de versão para usar mais de uma versão do node ao mesmo tempo. As instruções de instalação estão no `README` do projeto.

Depois de intalar instale a versão desejada do node:

```
nvm install v4
```

e após isso habilite seu uso:

```
nvm use v4
```

---

### Editado:

Tente habilitar algum proxy para as atualizações do npm, você pode fazer isso da seguinte maneira para um pacote apenas:

```
npm --proxy http://proxy-server:8080/ install {package-name}
```

Ou você pode setar a configuração global do proxy com:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port
```

Pergunta relacionada: [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)

[Aqui](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2728) você pode acompanhar uma issua relacionada sobre o bloqueio por firewall e o desvio disso com sucesso. E [aqui](https://superuser.com/questions/347476/how-to-install-npm-behind-authentication-proxy-on-windows) uma pergunta que foi migrada do stackoverflow para o superuser sobre problemas semelhantes que usaram a solução sugerida.

A única questão que resta é ter uma conexão para usar como proxy.

Comment: Instalei o nvm, tentei instalar com o "nvm install v4", mas acontece o mesmo que com o NPM, passa muito tempo e não instala(mais que o tempo de download no node.js e npm).

Comment: tente iniciar o terminal como administrador, para isso: clique com o botão direito do mouse no cmd e depois em abrir como administrador.

Comment: Continua a não funcionar

Comment: Eu não tenho uma conexão pra usar como proxy

Comment: Existem muitos proxys abertos na internet, o questão seriam a segurança do tráfego, mas enfim, é uma solução possível.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que voce não usou sudo, suponho que esteja usando npm pelo windows. Se estiver no windows, instale o git bash e logo após a instalação clique com o botão direito no git bash `-> run as administrator`, e rode novamente o comando.

Comment: Para no mesmo lugar

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi este problema **apagando da pasta .npm** da raiz do meu computador. Talvez isso funcione apenas no macOS e no Linux. No window não saberei como resolver. E depois de ter feito isso dei um "npm install" no projeto, e funcionou!

Answer (score -2):

Estava tendo o mesmo problema achei que pudesse ser algum problema com as versoes entao peguei um pacote desinstalei e depois instalei uma versao atual ai comecou a rodar normal