# npm não instala dependências e fica aparentemente travado

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, windows-10

Ao tentar instalar qualquer dependência não esta funcionando, ao buscar sobre isto algumas pessoas disseram que o motivo é o `npm` não encontrar a pasta para instalação, mas eu mudei o prefixo no `.npmrc` para outra pasta e nada.

**Nota:** Eu estou usando Windows 10 / npm 3.10.10 / node v6.11.1

```
C:\Users\hfn> npm install -verbose -g cordova ionic
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-verbose',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'cordova',
npm verb cli   'ionic' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.1
npm verb request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:07:48
npm verb request id 468c57296875de61
npm verb etag W/"5969831a-176ba9"
npm verb lastModified Sat, 15 Jul 2017 02:51:06 GMT
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm verb request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:07:48
npm verb etag W/"59692e74-164ec0"
npm verb lastModified Fri, 14 Jul 2017 20:49:56 GMT
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm verb headers { date: 'Sat, 15 Jul 2017 14:07:49 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"5969831a-176ba9"',
npm verb headers   age: '106',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-atl6235-ATL',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1500127670.820901,VS0,VE1',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
npm verb etag http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova from cache
npm verb get saving cordova to C:\Users\hfn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\cordova\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\hfn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb headers { date: 'Sat, 15 Jul 2017 14:07:52 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"59692e74-164ec0"',
npm verb headers   age: '270',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-atl6224-ATL',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1500127673.753196,VS0,VE1',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
npm verb etag http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic from cache
npm verb get saving ionic to C:\Users\hfn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\hfn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec cordova
npm verb cache add spec ionic
npm verb addNamed "latest" is being treated as a dist-tag for cordova
npm info addNameTag [ 'cordova', 'latest' ]
npm verb addNameTag registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova not in flight; fetching
npm verb addNamed "latest" is being treated as a dist-tag for ionic
npm info addNameTag [ 'ionic', 'latest' ]
npm verb addNameTag registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic not in flight; fetching
npm verb get http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova not expired, no request
npm verb addNamed "7.0.1" is a plain semver version for cordova
npm verb get http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic not expired, no request
npm verb addNamed "3.5.0" is a plain semver version for ionic
npm verb addRemoteTarball http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-7.0.1.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-7.0.1.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '69fd054300ce5105b092f67a1b286e80c4e88b9d' ]
npm verb addRemoteTarball http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-3.5.0.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-3.5.0.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '9174d9acad1e668ade8b0e39d4ae39894238b31e' ]
[    ..............] | loadRequestedDeps: verb addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-3.5.0.tgz',
```

Comment: Tente algumas destas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155799/3635